# With NSwag for C# how do we create multiple client classes for different API in the same client project

Tags: c#, api, nswag

I have successfully created a Client class for my API using NSwag generator.

But how do I create another Client class for my second API using NSwag generator

I use NSwag as it generators an Interface for the Client class and other great things

Comment: I believe it's better to describe your problem here with more details step-by-step

Answer (score -1):

NSwag supports more than one configuration.

api1.json api2.json api3.json

If running CLI, call each one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).